# MySQL error after updating phpBB 3.0.12 to 3.1

Tags: mysql, sql, phpbb3

I'm currently in the process of updating my phpBB installation to 3.1 and I got this when the database was being updated to the latest stable version.

```
SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 1=1' at line 3 [1064]

SQL

UPDATE bb_users SET user_style = WHERE 1=1

BACKTRACE

FILE: (not given by php)
LINE: (not given by php)
CALL: msg_handler()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/driver.php
LINE: 855
CALL: trigger_error()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/mysqli.php
LINE: 194
CALL: phpbb\db\driver\driver->sql_error()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/driver/factory.php
LINE: 329
CALL: phpbb\db\driver\mysqli->sql_query()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/migration/data/v31x/style_update.php
LINE: 101
CALL: phpbb\db\driver\factory->sql_query()

FILE: (not given by php)
LINE: (not given by php)
CALL: phpbb\db\migration\data\v31x\style_update->update_installed_styles()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/migrator.php
LINE: 510
CALL: call_user_func_array()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/migrator.php
LINE: 456
CALL: phpbb\db\migrator->run_step()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/migrator.php
LINE: 294
CALL: phpbb\db\migrator->process_data_step()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/migrator.php
LINE: 234
CALL: phpbb\db\migrator->try_apply()

FILE: [ROOT]/phpbb/db/migrator.php
LINE: 174
CALL: phpbb\db\migrator->try_apply()

FILE: [ROOT]/install/database_update.php
LINE: 206
CALL: phpbb\db\migrator->update()
```

I'm using the Automatic Update Package.

I've tried searching through the database in phpMyAdmin, but I couldn't find anything useful. I have no experience with SQL and very little with PHP, so I'd like some instructions on what to do. A friend who knows more about SQL told me SET might be empty, but I don't really know what to do with that information.

Comment: Looks like there's something missing before the `WHERE` clause: `UPDATE bb_users SET user_style = WHERE 1=1`

Comment: I think I got it. The prosilver style was missing some files. If anyone else gets this error, try downloading a new phpbb 3.1 zip file and replace the prosilver style on your server with the new one.